# Инлайн-редактирование меток в результатах поиска

Tags: предложение

Для удобства выпиливания лишних меток хотелось бы иметь возможность их инлайнового редактирования на страницах с результатами поиска.

Comment: - Почему ты пищишь после приёма таблеток? - Так написано в инструкции: "после приёма пищи".

Comment: @alexolut, ага)))

Comment: В результатах поиска ведь вообще не выводятся метки.

Comment: @alexolut, да ну? https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2o2T.png

Comment: видимо я спутал с ответами при поиске.